# How to set the GTK4 tooltip delay in gtk-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

I can do like

```
let button = Button::builder().label("Click me..!")
                              .tooltip_text("You have to click this..!")
                              .margin_top(24)
                              .margin_bottom(24)
                              .margin_start(12)
                              .margin_end(12)
                              .build();
```

and when hovered the button shows the tooltip with a certain delay. Yet i would like to shorten it's timeout to show earlier. Despite all kinds of AI and GPT and whatnot it turned out to be an impossible mission. This is with GTK4 with dependencies in `cargo.toml` defined as

```
[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.6.6", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_10"] }
```

Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover timeout for tooltips has been fixed to 500 ms (or 60 ms when browsing from another tooltip) since GTK+ 3.9.8, in commit [`e61c1245`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/commit/e61c1245096e46fda3385afa5c0dcd8e3574d51f). Even before then, it was configurable only for the entire application, not for individual widgets. To use an earlier timeout, you'll have to create your own popup from scratch; you may find [`EventControllerMotion`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.EventControllerMotion.html) and [`Popover`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Popover.html) helpful for that.

Comment: Any idea why was the configuration deprecated?

Comment: @Cokegod In https://discourse.gnome.org/t/tooltip-timeout/1101, one of the devs gives a justification for not re-adding it, though I can't speak for the exact reasoning for why it was removed at the time.